# CLPlacemark location gives district info too, why?

Tags: ios, mapkit, clplacemark

I need only the city info of client recent location and not district. Any idea how to avoid?

`pm.locality` returns: `Budapest VII. kerület`, I would expect only `Budapest`.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(locations.first as CLLocation, completionHandler: {placemarks, error in

            let pm = placemarks.first as CLPlacemark
```

Comment: How are you obtaining the CLPlacemark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would expect

That's your problem right there. CLPlacemarks obtained by reverse geocoding categorize their pieces the way *they* categorize them, not the way *you* expect.

So the solution here is to stop expecting and start *dealing* with the placemark so that you can obtain the results you *want*. For example, try extracting the placemark's `addressDictionary` and see if you can use its categorizations any more easily.

Also, try examining other properties of the placemark. Maybe its `sublocality` is closer to what you are hoping for. Or maybe it's some other property.

Comment: you are right, this way I can get city info: `let city = pm.addressDictionary["State"] as String` hopefully this is how it works for other client at other location in the world

Comment: @János Unfortunately it's different for different countries; it all depends on how the country is organized and how the database is categorized to match. Addresses are like dates - they're really complicated!